# symfony upload file null in controller

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I try upload file with vichUploaderBundle but in controller I have null value in attribut picture(attribut file from vichuploaderBundle).... I write code from doc vichUploadBundle but error is in form :

code view:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
  <div class="justify-content-center row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      {{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('new_doctor'),'attr':{'enctype': 'multipart/form-data','id': 'regForm', 'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}

      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.email,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Email'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.firstName,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'firstName'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.firstName) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.lastName,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'lastName'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.lastName) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.region,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Region'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.region) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.shortBio,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'shortBio'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.shortBio) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.streetAddress,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'streetAddress'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.streetAddress) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.postalCode,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'postalCode'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.postalCode) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.locality,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'locality'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.locality) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.country,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'country'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.country) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.speciality,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'speciality'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.speciality) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.picture,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.picture) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first,{ 'attr': {'class':'form-control' ,'placeholder': 'Password'} }) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second,{ 'attr': {'class':'form-control' ,'placeholder': 'Repeat your password'} }) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.bio,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'bio'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.bio) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
      </div>
      {{ form_rest(form) }}
      <div class="form-group float-right" style="margin-top: 2%">
        <input type="submit" class="submitRegister btn btn-primary" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group float-left">
        <a class="loginInRegister nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLogin">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
        </a>
      </div>

      {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

controller:

```
        public function new(Request $request){
      $user = new Doctor();
      $user->setEnabled(true);
      $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
      $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

      if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
      }

      $form= $this->createForm(DoctorType::class, $user);
      $form->setData($user);

      $form->handleRequest($request);
      if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

        if ($form->isValid()) {
          $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
          $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);
          //dump($user->getPicture());die;
          $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
          $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

          $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

          return $response;
        }
      $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
      $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);
      if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
        return $response;
      }


      }

      return [
        'form' => $form->createView()
      ];
    }
```

formType:

```
<?php

  namespace App\Form\Type;

  use App\Entity\Doctor;
  use App\Entity\User;
  use PhpParser\Comment\Doc;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

  class DoctorType extends AbstractType
  {
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {
          $builder
              ->remove('username')
              ->add('firstName')
              ->add('lastName')
              ->add('shortBio')
              ->add('bio',TextareaType::class)
              ->add('streetAddress')
              ->add('postalCode')
              ->add('locality')
              ->add('region')
              ->add('picture',FileType::class)
              ->add('country')
              ->add('speciality')
          ;
      }

    /**
     * @return FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
     */
    public function getParent()

    {
      return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()

    {
      return 'app_doctor_registration';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()

    {
      return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

      public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
      {
          $resolver->setDefaults([
              'data_class' => Doctor::class,
          ]);
      }
  }
```

code of entity is code of document vichUploadBundle and I have any error in flush .. object is flush in database but picture dosen't move to directory or persist picture in database

Comment: this is not enough to debug. we need the controller, the formType and only the relevant code

Comment: @goto I upadate my answer and i add code controller and formType